# How to limit tkinter treeview width in a grid

Tags: tkinter, treeview, ttk

So I have been stuck on this for two days now and I am losing it. I am just learning python myself and just three weeks in, please forgive any newbie mistakes.
With tkinter I am building an app to read and filter csv files and when the user selects a file I want to display the first 10 rows of data as a preview so they know what the data looks like.

When I load the file, I fill a treeview with the data and then I would like to show the treeview in the app. When I do this the treeview expands all the way on the x-axis to fit it's contents and with that pushing everything on it's right out of the screen.

Is there a way to have a treeview with a lot of columns to show to stay a certain max width and then scroll on the x-axis (I know this has to be done with a ttk.scrollbar)?

The whole code I have is this:

```
#------------ Import modules
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import ttkbootstrap as tb

import os

from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#------------ Version information
title = "Datascraper"
version = "v1.1.1"

#------------ Create window
root = tb.Window(themename="superhero")
root.title(f"{title} {version}")
root.iconbitmap('../assets/images/Icon.ico')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1100, 900))

#------------ Global variables
fileloaded = "False"

#------------ Images
logoObject = Image.open("../assets/images/Logo.png").resize((100, 100))
logoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logoObject)

#------------ Styling
buttonwidth = 15

#------------ Functions
def selectFile():
    global fileloaded
    if fileloaded == "False":
        # Select a file
        root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/C:",
                                                   title="Select file",
                                                   filetypes=(("CSV files", "*csv"), ("All files", "*.*"))
                                                   )
        filepath = root.filename
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(root.filename))[0]
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(filepath))

        # Show filename
        selected_file_label.config(text=f"Selected file: {filename}")
        fileloaded = filename

        def fileLength(): # Check how many rows are in the dataset
            try:
                length = sum(1 for row in open(filepath, 'r'))
                return length // 100
            except (FileNotFoundError):
                pass

        # Fill the progressbar
        length = fileLength()
        changeFrames(loadPreviewFrame)
        for columns in enumerate(pd.read_csv(filepath, chunksize=length, low_memory=False)):
            progress = columns[0]
            preview_progressbar.configure(value=progress)
            root.update_idletasks()
        changeFrames(previewFrame)
        previewFrame_label.config(text="File preview (first 10 rows)")

        # Generate a preview of the file with the first 10 rows
        file_preview_treeview["column"] = list(df.columns)
        df_rows = df.head(10).to_numpy().tolist()
        for column in file_preview_treeview["column"]:
            file_preview_treeview.heading(column, text=column, anchor="w")
            file_preview_treeview.column(column, width=120, anchor="w", stretch=0)
        for row in df_rows:
            file_preview_treeview.insert("", "end", values=row)
        file_preview_treeview.pack()

    else:
        pass # This is just for now, I will add a messagebox later

def changeFrames(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
    frame.grid(row=1, sticky="new")

#------------ Frames
menuFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=150)
loadPreviewFrame = tb.Frame(root, width=800, height=200)
previewFrame = tb.Frame(root, width=800, height=275)
treeviewFrame = tb.Frame(previewFrame, width=800, height=275)
filterFrame = tb.Frame(root, width=800, height=550)
resultFrame = tb.Frame(root, width=400, height=500)
footerFrame = tb.Frame(root, width=800, height=50)



#------------ Buttons
logoLabel = tb.Button(menuFrame, image=logoImage, bootstyle="link")
logoLabel.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky="w", padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0))

select_file_button = tb.Button(menuFrame,
                                text="Select file",
                                width=buttonwidth,
                                bootstyle="outline",
                                command=selectFile)
select_file_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20, 5), pady=(20, 0), sticky="w")

filter_file_button = tb.Button(menuFrame,
                                text="Filter file",
                                bootstyle="outline",
                                width=buttonwidth)
filter_file_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(5, 5), pady=(20, 0), sticky="w")

save_results_button = tb.Button(resultFrame,
                                text="Save rapport",
                                bootstyle="outline",
                                width=buttonwidth)
save_results_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 0), sticky="w")

#------------ Comboboxes


#------------ Invulvelden


#------------ Labels
selected_file_label = tb.Label(menuFrame,
                               text="No file selected")
selected_file_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 0), sticky="w")

previewFrame_label = tb.Label(previewFrame,
                              text="")
previewFrame_label.pack()

resultFrame_label = tb.Label(resultFrame,
                             text="Filtered results:")
resultFrame_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="n", pady=(10, 0))

#------------ Listboxes


#------------ Progressbars
preview_progressbar = tb.Floodgauge(loadPreviewFrame,
                                    mask="Loading... {}%",
                                    maximum=100)
preview_progressbar.grid(row=1, column=0)

#------------ Placeholders (labels zonder inhoud)
#menuPlaceholder = tk.Label(menuFrame, image=menuPlaceholderImage)
#menuPlaceholder.grid(row=0, column=3)

#------------ Separators


#------------ Textfields


#------------ Treeviews
file_preview_treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeviewFrame)

#------------ Scrollbars

#------------ Grid configuraties
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

menuFrame.grid(row=0, sticky="new")
previewFrame.grid(row=1, sticky="new")
loadPreviewFrame.grid(row=1, sticky="new")
treeviewFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
filterFrame.grid(row=2, sticky="nesw")
footerFrame.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, sticky="esw")
resultFrame.grid(row=0, rowspan=6, column=1, sticky="nesw")

root.mainloop()
```

Any help in the good direction is very much appreciated

I have tried creating a treeview in a packed frame (instead of a grid frame) in the root and that one does fit the screen and I can scroll on the x-axis but that way I can not make the layout I want.

I tried treeview.pack / treeview.grid / treeview.place but nothing seems to work and I get the same result all the time
When I limit the maximum columns to show by only putting 5 columns inside the treeview the treeview is small enough to stay within it's screen.